# selecting 3 columns in asp.net and joining the string results

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, select

so here, i'm aiming to select the 3 columns, studentlastname, studentfirstname, and studentmiddleinitial from my database, STUD_DB, so here's the code :

```
    public string selectname(string email)
{
    string name;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    string select = "SELECT studentlastname,studentfirstname,studentmiddleinitial FROM STUD_DB WHERE emailaddress = @mail";
    SqlCommand sel = new SqlCommand(select, con);

    sel.Parameters.Add("@mail", email);

    //this is where idk what to do. 
}
```

my concern is, after i select the 3 columns, i want to place them in separate variables, then join them to one string, resulting to the student's full name, but, i don't know how to code that part. :) will wait for an answer, and thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code load correctly the data from the database (use always parametrized query, never string concatenation). You need only to read the data retrieved by a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9ttex).

```
public string selectname(string email) 
{ 
    string name; 
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string select = "SELECT studentlastname,studentfirstname,studentmiddleinitial " + 
                        "FROM STUD_DB WHERE emailaddress = @mail"; 
        SqlCommand sel = new SqlCommand(select, con); 
        sel.Parameters.Add("@mail", email);
        SqlDataReader dr = sel.ExecuteReader();
        while(dr.Read())
            name = string.Join(" ", dr.GetString(0), dr.GetString(1), dr.GetString(2));
    }
    return name;
}
```

Also, the using statement is real lifesaver, this will avoid to forget close/dispose the connection

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the full name in your query:

```
const string @select = "SELECT studentlastname + ' ' " +
                               "+ studentfirstname + ' ' " +
                               "+ studentmiddleinitial as FullName " +
                               "FROM STUD_DB WHERE emailaddress = @mail";


using (var connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(select, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.Add("mail", email);
        return command.ExecuteScalar() as string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use the parameters, you can simply add the string. Not the most bragable solution but will work.

```
private void GetData(String email)
{
  String sqlStatement = "select * from Programs where Something = " + email;
  try
  {
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, _CONNECTION_STRING))
    {
      DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("Items");
      adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Items");
    }
    }
  catch (Exception) { }
  // Here you just type "dataSet." and the intellisense will 
  // present you with options to access the tables, rows etc.
}
```

Comment: Don't use parameter will not prevent sql injection

Comment: True. That's why i said "if you don't want to use parameters". If it's a small school project and the guy is confused about some fundamental concepts, it might be an idea to give him a hand at his level. I agree with you in general, though.